# Facebook login page showing blank page in IOS 9

Tags: objective-c, ios9, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am using FBSDKCoreKit (4.12.0) FBSDKLoginKit (4.12.0) 
first i am getting screen 1

This method is block is never called .

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    //never called
}];
```

getting this warning

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <FBSDKContainerViewController: 0x16570810> on <ViewController: 0x16528870> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

[image]

Then i press ok button i am getting blank page without moving to any other page

[image]

Plist file i used is

For Transpost security

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>facebook.com</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                </dict>
                <key>fbcdn.net</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>

Query schems


    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbauth</string>
            <string>fbapi</string>
            <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
            <string>fbauth2</string>
            <string>fbshareextension</string>
            <string>fbapi20130214</string>
            <string>fbapi20130410</string>
            <string>fbapi20130702</string>
            <string>fbapi20131010</string>
            <string>fbapi20131219</string>
            <string>fbapi20131219</string>
            <string>fbapi20140410</string>
            <string>fbapi20140116</string>
            <string>fbapi20150313</string>
            <string>fbapi20150629</string>
            <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>fb268237443567174</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>FacebookAppID</key>
        <string>268237443567174</string>
        <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
        <string>MyAPP</string>
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @marco Grieco : yes solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How i found solution for the above problem is

1)Earlier i have created a button and given FBLoginButton class and in action i wrote like

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    //never called
}];
```

Modification for solution: Removed the FBLoginButton class and put only UIButton

2)Use both ios 8 and ios 9 methods like below written in AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                       annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation
            ];
}
```

Comment: I cannot seem to add two methods in appdelegate, Duplicate declaration error showing up

Comment: Same issue coming bro "Duplicate declaration" How did it work for you ? I copied and pasted only

Comment: @SuperXtreem second contains "annotation" keyword but first does not contain then how can you get duplicate ?

Comment: can u pls share ur mail id? i will send you the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

I used did code to sign in Fabook, both work fine on iOS 8 and 9. Hope this helps you.

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"email,name,first_name,last_name"}] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
           //Login success and callback here
        } else {
           //Login failed
        }
    }];
```