# Facebook login after get permissions let Safari blank page open instead of redirect to my app in iOS 10 and iOS 11

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios10, ios11

I am implementing Facebook Login in my app.

All is working property except the redirection to my app after Facebook get permissions.

A Safari blank page is handle opened instead of redirect to my app. I read in soy many forums and other Stack Overflow questions about a similar problem in iOS 9, that is fixed using this code in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> 
*)options {

     return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] 
                                                application:application
                                                    openURL:url
                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  }

  return YES;
}
```

I already check that when I give Facebook permissions this code works properly but still doesn't redirect to my app, only redirect to a new Safari blank page where the only option that I have is press **OK** or **Done** button that send me in the loginManager method to the **user cancelled request** case

[image: (1) Allow Facebook to read permissions]

[image: (2) Redirect to a Safari blank page]

There is my FBLoginManger code

```
self.manager =[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  NSArray *facebookPermissions = @[@"email", @"public_profile", @"user_friends"];

  if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] != nil) {
    [self.manager logOut];
    //return
  }

    [self.manager logInWithReadPermissions: facebookPermissions fromViewController: self handler: ^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult* result, NSError* error ) {
      if (error != nil) {
        //According to Facebook:
        //Errors will rarely occur in the typical login flow because the login dialog
        //presented by Facebook via single sign on will guide the users to resolve any errors.

        NSLog(@"FACEBOOK LOGIN ERROR %@", error);
        // Process error
        [self.manager logOut];
      } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations
        [self.manager logOut];
      } else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        BOOL allPermsGranted = true;

        NSArray *grantedPermissions = [[result grantedPermissions] allObjects];

        NSString *lastObject = [grantedPermissions lastObject];

        for (NSString *permission in facebookPermissions) {
          for (NSString* grantedPerm in grantedPermissions) {
            NSRange range = [permission rangeOfString:grantedPerm];
            if ((range.length == 0) && (grantedPerm == lastObject)) {
              allPermsGranted = false;
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if (allPermsGranted) {
          // Do work
          //NSString * fbToken = [[result token] tokenString];
          NSString * fbUserID = [[result token] userID];

          FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                        initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                                        parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,name,email"}
                                        HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

          [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil) {
              NSDictionary *dict = @{
                                     @"email" : [result objectForKey:@"email"] ,
                                     @"providerID" : fbUserID,
                                     @"username" : [result objectForKey:@"name"],
                                     @"provider" : @"facebook"
                                     };
              NSLog(@"DICT %@", dict);
              [self.delegate loginWithCredentials:dict];
              [self logUserLoggedInWithFacebookEvent];
            } else {
              NSLog(@"ERROR FACEBOOK %@", error);
            }
          }];

        } else {
          //The user did not grant all permissions requested
          //Discover which permissions are granted
          //and if you can live without the declined ones
          NSLog(@"FACEBOOK LOGIN ERROR");
          [self.manager logOut];
        }
      }
    }];
```

The method is called but always drop in `result.isCancelled` case

Comment: canyou print the error `NSLog(@"FACEBOOK LOGIN ERROR %@", error);`

Comment: Never drop in that case, only redirect to the safari page and then my unique option is to press OK button that is cancel the result. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Look in this code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7lSqbQq9-WuYU9qNlhOdWczU2M/view?usp=sharing  Same as your code.

Comment: Thank you @Gagan_iOS you have already sent me that code but in my project it isn't still working. I have the code exactly than yours but something isn't working properly

Comment: @origds - plz file a bug in facebook, the problem is redirect

Comment: I know what mistake you are doing. Open storyboard of the app that I sent to you. You will find a button with title 'Login' having from class 'FBSDKLoginButton'. There is IBOutlet in .h file as @property (weak, nonatomic)  FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton;  You have to perform the same setup in your code with IBOutlet.

Now look into ViewDidLoad method. Just copy code from ViewDidLoad. Everything will work.

Comment: @origds - change your login behaviour to web and try once

Comment: did you get success or still struggling?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I can't continue working on the project now, tomorrow I will implement the solution that you propose and I will notify you. Thank you.

Comment: no issue. Happy to help :) connect gagan5278@gmail.com if you need urgent help

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik change the login behaviour does not prevent that safari page appears

Comment: @origds - see this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319937/canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-osstatus-error-10814/46321192#46321192

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried using SystemAccount behaviour and the result is the same, I think that the problem isn't the login behaviour, it seems like after get the permissions can't redirect to my app again and respond in a weird way. Just now I tried again with the code that you send and have the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the error deleting the FBLoginButton and replacing it by a UIButton which is associated to my IBAction that calls the FBLoginManager function.

The answer is based on this question [Facebook login page showing blank page in IOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874383/facebook-login-page-showing-blank-page-in-ios-9)
and its answer by [@MuraliMohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4608736/muralimohan)